# Neovim tries to run vale through a Autocommand

Tags: neovim, save, plugin-treesitter, mason, linting

Whenever I save a `.txt`  file it I get the error:

```
Error detected while processing BufWritePost Autocommands for "*":
Error running vale: ENOENT: no such file or directory
```

I have tried using `:TSUpdate`, installing and uninstalling vale and vale_ls through Mason and googling, but nothing worked

### `:checkhealth nvim-treesitter`

```
nvim-treesitter: require("nvim-treesitter.health").check()
Installation ~
- OK `tree-sitter` found 0.20.8 (0c49d6745b3fc4822ab02e0018770cd6383a779c) (parser generator, only needed for :TSInstallFromGrammar)
- OK `node` found v18.16.0 (only needed for :TSInstallFromGrammar)
- OK `git` executable found.
- OK `cc` executable found. Selected from { vim.NIL, "cc", "gcc", "clang", "cl", "zig" }
  Version: cc (Rev7, Built by MSYS2 project) 13.1.0
- OK Neovim was compiled with tree-sitter runtime ABI version 14 (required >=13). Parsers must be compatible with runtime ABI.

OS Info:
{
  machine = "x86_64",
  release = "10.0.22621",
  sysname = "Windows_NT",
  version = "Windows 11 Home"
} ~

Parser/Features         H L F I J

  Legend: H[ighlight], L[ocals], F[olds], I[ndents], In[j]ections
         +) multiple parsers found, only one will be used
         x) errors found in the query, try to run :TSUpdate {lang} ~
```

Comment: Check the output of `:verbose :au BufWritePost *`  and verify where the faulty autocommand has been setup and disable it.